# Aerospike ListOperation usage in Java client

Tags: aerospike

I'm getting started with the ListOperation in the Java client, and the operations do not work as expected. Here are my code:

```
AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient("10.0.0.1", 3000);
Key key = new Key("test", "demo", "testlist");

Value vll = Value.get(123);

List<Value> itemList = new ArrayList<Value>();
itemList.add(Value.get("s11"));
itemList.add(Value.get("s22222"));
Bin bin01 = new Bin("bin3", Value.get(itemList));

client.put(null, key, bin01);
Record record0 = client.operate(null, key, Operation.put(new Bin("bin4", 90)), ListOperation.insertItems("bin6", 0, itemList) , Operation.get());
System.out.println("record0");
System.out.println(record0);
Record record1 = client.operate(null, key, ListOperation.append("bin3", vll), Operation.get());
System.out.println("record1");
System.out.println(record1);

itemList.add(Value.get("s3333333"));
itemList.add(Value.get("s4444444444"));
itemList.add(Value.get("s5555555555555555"));
Record record2 = client.operate(null, key,
        ListOperation.insertItems("bin3", 0, itemList), Operation.get()
);
System.out.println("record2");
System.out.println(record2);

Record record3 = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println("record3");
System.out.println(record3);
```

And here are the output:

> record0 (gen:2),(exp:239021264),(bins:(bin3:[s11, s22222]),(bin4:90))
>   record1 (gen:3),(exp:239021264),(bins:(bin3:[s11, s22222]),(bin4:90))
>   record2 (gen:4),(exp:239021265),(bins:(bin3:[s11, s22222]),(bin4:90))
>   record3 (gen:4),(exp:239021265),(bins:(bin3:[s11, s22222]),(bin4:90))

It seems that all of the ListOperations used in my code were not applied. Am I using it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This issue is also being discussed here:  https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/listoperation-usage/4316/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need Server version 3.7.0.1+ to do the above ListOperations. Testing on ver 3.3.21.